# Список меток в вопросе и на его странице редактирования отличается

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Берем этот вопрос: [Как заставить rake не выводить backtrace в случае ошибки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8341)

В нем всего одна метка: [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby)

Открываю редактор через правку и там уже: [rakefile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rakefile), [rake](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rake), [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby)

Если я хочу добавить метку, то мне какие метки (+ своя метка) нужно предлагать к изменению -- с самого вопроса или с страницы редактирования?

Comment: а у меня в редактировании остается та же одна метка

Comment: А метки, которые я тут описал, показываются кликабельными? А то я в редакторе в предпросмотре вижу их кликабельными, а тут как есть

Comment: @Grundy, по вопросу: почистил куки -- не помогло.

Comment: чтобы они были кликабельными - нужно кавычки убрать. и нет - я вижу только одну метку для этого вопроса, что в режиме просмотра, что в режиме редактирования

Comment: Вижу, после правки так и есть. Но, в предпросмотре они и с кавычками были кликабельны, почему?

Comment: Мне кажется это уже отдельный вопрос по мете и редактору/предпросмотру должен быть :)

Comment: да, его уже оформил вопрос, но не хотел поднимать бучу -- вдруг такая фича :)

Comment: Подтверждаю, у меня тот же баг.

Comment: У меня 3 метки при попытке редактировать их.

Comment: Вроде удалил лишние метки, добавив новую.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а вот если наткнусь на такую фигню, мне брать метки с вопроса? Или с страницы редактирования?

Comment: @gil9red думаю, стоит здравым сыслом руководствоваться и ставить те, которые отражают суть вопроса. Тут обе дополнительных метки очень редкие, так что я оставил только [tag:rake].

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и [tag:ruby]

Comment: @gil9red ну да, с ней-то всё хорошо было сразу.